# Finding the position of a DOM element relative to the window?

Tags: javascript

I have found many people asking this question and the answers all involve getting the offset then doing some calculations to include the scroll positions.

But what if the element might be in a parent element that is position:fixed?

Is there a much easier way to calculate the element's position?

Comment: Just get its offset and not worry about scroll positions?

Comment: Are you saying that the parent is "position:fixed"?

Comment: @frosty The parent may or may not be fixed.

Comment: The answers here may provide some insight to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try element.getBoundingClientRect(); This shouldn't need you to use scroll positions in your calculations.